# Cant Convert List of Type<T> to List of Type<T>

Tags: c#

I get told I cannot convert From System generic List to a List of the Exact same type:

```
 public JsonResult People()
        {
            var test = new List<People>();
            var page = "";
            var pageNumber = "1";
            SharpEntityResults<People> results = null;

            while (page != "" || page != null)
            {
               results = starCore.GetAllPeople(pageNumber);
                List<People> x = results.results;
                test.Add(x);
            }
```

```
 public class People : SharpEntity
```

```
  public SharpEntityResults<People> GetAllPeople(string pageNumber = "1")
        {
            SharpEntityResults<People> result = GetAllPaginated<People>("/people/", pageNumber);

            return result;
        }
```

Not sure why I cant add to my test List when both are of the same type

The Error States:

> cannot convert from
> System.Collections.Generic>List<ProjectName.Entitites.People> to
> Projectname.Entitites.People

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: The error states that an object of type `List<People>` (the object being `x`) cannot be converted to an object of type `People` (i.e. the type of each element in `test`). It does not state that the two objects are of the same type.

Answer (score 1):

`test` is a `List<People>` and `x` is also a `List<People>`, so you are trying to add a list to a list. Try to use `AddRange` instead.

This way you will add all items from `x` to the list `test`.

Comment: Ooh Right I didnt think of that, I just thought I had to match types It didnt come accross to me I had to rethink how im adding Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You've a mistake in your code.

`List<People> x` holds objects of type `People`, if you want to store x in test you need it to be of type `List<List<People>>` or `List<IEnumerable<People>>` if you want to add content of x to test you can do `test.AddRange(x)` this will put / add content of X to the list of Test.

Examples of how to fix this with left hand type declaration for clarity.

For Storing Content of X in Test:

```
 public JsonResult People()
    {
        List<People> test = new List<People>();
        var page = "";
        var pageNumber = "1";
        SharpEntityResults<People> results = null;

        while (page != "" || page != null)
        {
           results = starCore.GetAllPeople(pageNumber);
            List<People> x = results.results;
            test.AddRange(x);
        }
```

If you want to store Lists then your code will look like this.

```
public JsonResult People()
    {
        List<IEnumerable<People>> test = new List<List<People>>();
        var page = "";
        var pageNumber = "1";
        SharpEntityResults<People> results = null;

        while (page != "" || page != null)
        {
           results = starCore.GetAllPeople(pageNumber);
            List<People> x = results.results;
            test.Add(x);
        }
```

In that case you'll have for each entry a List